# GPS Point to static map Action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dictionary, gps

What I am doing wrong? I donot geting numbers trace shows Infinity

```
function geolocationUpdateHandler(event: GeolocationEvent): void {
event.latitude.toString();
event.longitude.toString();
trace(lat = event.latitude);
trace(lng = event.longitude);
trace(Star.x = (((lng * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLongitude * Math.PI / 180)) /  ((MaxLongitude * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLongitude * Math.PI / 180)) / Map.width));
trace(Star.y = (((lat * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLatitude* Math.PI / 180)) / ((MaxLatitude * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLatitude * Math.PI / 180)) / Map.height));
```

}

```
var MinLongitude:int; 
MinLongitude = 25.139585;
var MaxLongitude:int; 
MaxLongitude = 25.332134;
var MaxLatitude:int; 
MaxLatitude = 57.790398;
var MinLatitude:int; 
MinLatitude = 57.693223;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the long/latitudes return as converted to [text] string. No need for `.toString` method.

Correct way to trace is example: `trace("my latitude is.. " + event.location);`

In your code try like this:

```
trace( "lat = " + event.latitude );
trace( "lng = " + event.longitude );

trace( "Star.x = " + (((lng * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLongitude... etc
trace( "Star.y = " + (((lat * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLatitude... etc
```

**Edit:**

I just realised you're casting `int` as the type for your four vars (`var MinLongitude:int` etc) but also setting them up with fractional inputs. `Int's` cannot be fractions or have decimal places so change those types to `Number` eg: (`var MinLongitude:Number`) etc. Hopefully now you'll get good results.

Otherwise seems there is nothing with your calculation formula. So minus infinity is strange. I did manual calculation...

```
Star.x = (((lng * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLongitude * Math.PI / 180)) /  ((MaxLongitude * Math.PI / 180) - (MinLongitude * Math.PI / 180)) / Map.width));
```

in calculator becomes: (assume Map.width = 500, Math.PI = 3.14)...

```
(25.33213 * 3.14 / 180) - (25.139585 * 3.14 / 180) /  (25.332134 * 3.14 / 180) - (25.139585 * 3.14 / 180) / 500
```

and the result 6.077202837190 etc.... so `Star.x = 6.0`

Comment: Star.x = -Infinity
Star.y = -Infinity
lat = 57.79039
lng = 25.33213

Comment: the problem is not in trace the problem is that I am not getnig number of Star.x , y but the infinity there is something wrong with degrees and radians

Comment: Try `:Number` instead of `:int` on your coordinates